# How can we prove that there are no other integers with $\phi(n)=2$ besides 3,4,6?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

Where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's phi function that counts the number of relatively prime integers less than or equal to n.

I've been able to compute that 3,4,6 all have only 2 relatively prime integers less than or equal to them, however I'm unsure how to *prove* that there are indeed no others. While I am certain that this is the case, how can this be proved rigorously?

Comment: Use the product formula for $\varphi(n)$, given the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: @Lulu I agree, and that is what I've tried to use. But using that formula how can you see that there are no other possibilities without actually plugging in all possible combinations of primes?

Comment: Of course.  First argue that, since $p\,|\,n\implies (p-1)\,|\,\varphi(n)$, we can't have any prime $>3$ dividing $n$.  Then argue that we can't have $2^3\,|\,n$ nor can we have $3^2\,|\,n$.  That just leaves you the cases you found.

Comment: There is also [Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+} : \phi(n)=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043607/find-all-n-in-mathbbz-phin-2) and

Comment: @Sil, the issue for me is not identifying which n satisfy \phi(n)=2, it's how to show that there are no others.

Comment: Of course, the same as in linked posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trickiest thing about this proof is figuring out how to organize the casework. Here's one way to do it:

If $n = 2^k$ is a power of two then $\varphi(n) = 2^{k-1}$ so we see that we can only have $k = 2$, so $n = \boxed{4}$.

Otherwise, $n$ has some odd prime power factor $p^k$, and then $\varphi(n)$ must be divisible by $\varphi(p^k) = (p-1) p^{k-1}$. Since $p$ is odd, $2 \mid (p-1)$, so $\varphi(p^k)$ will be strictly larger than $2$ unless $p = 3, k = 1$. So now we must have $n = 2^k \cdot 3$, which gives $\varphi(n) = 2^k$ for $k \ge 1$, hence $k = 1$, so $n = \boxed{6}$, or $\varphi(3) = 2$ for $k = 0$, so $n = \boxed{3}$.

*Exercise.* Generalize this argument to show that for any $m$ there are finitely many $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = m$. Can you compute which $n$ these are for other small values of $m$, say $m = 4$ or $m = 6$? (Hint: prove it in two stages. First prove that there are only finitely many possible prime factors for $n$. Second prove that the exponent of each of these prime factors is bounded. Working through the small cases $m = 4$ and $m = 6$ first would be a good idea as a warmup.)

Answer (score 1):

First prove that if $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ is the unique prime factorization of $n$ then $\phi(n) = \prod p_i^{k_i - 1} \prod (p_i - 1)$.  You should have already proven this.  The statement is totally equivalent to: 1) if $\gcd(a,b)= 1$ then $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi (b)$ and $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ if $p$ is prime and 2) $\phi( n )= n\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac 1p)$.

Then we have $2 = \prod p_i^{k_i -1} \prod (p_i-1)$.  The only way that can happen is if either i) $\prod p^{k_i-1} = 2$ and $\prod (p_i-1) = 1$ or if ii) $\prod p_i^{k_i-1} = 1$ and $\prod (p_i-1) = 2$.

If i) then $\prod (p_i-1) = 1$ imples $\{p_i\} = \{2\}$ and $\prod p^{k_i-1} = 2^1$ implies $\{p_i\} = 2$ and $k_i = 2$ so $n = 2^2 = 4$.

if ii) then $\prod p_i^{k_i-1} = 1$ implies $k_i =1$ of all the $p_i$ and $n = \prod p_i$, a square-free number.  Then $\prod (p_i - 1) =2$ implies that one of the $p_i-1 = 2$ and all the *other* $p_j$ (if any) are $p_j -1 = 1$. One of the prime factors is $3$ and if there is any other prime factor it can only be $2$.  but there need not be any other prime factor.  So we could have $n=3$ or $n=2\cdot 3 = 6$.

....

If that was too hand-wavy, here is a coffin with a few dozen nails:

Suppose $p> 3$ is a prime divisor of $n=\prod p_i^{k_i}$.  Then $\phi(n) = \prod p_i^{k_i - 1} \prod (p_i - 1)$ so $p-1|\phi(n)$.  But $p-1 > 2$ so $\phi(n) > 2$.  So if $\phi(n) = 2$ then $n$ has no prime divisors greater than $3$.

So $n = 2^a$ or $n = 3^b$ or $n=2^a3^b$ or $n = 1$.

If $n = 2^a$ then $\phi(n) = 2^{a-1}(2-1) = 2^{a-1}=2$.  So $a-1 =1$ and $a=2$ and $n = 2^2 = 4$.

If $n=3^b$ then $\phi(n) = 3^{b-1}(3-1) = 2\cdot 3^{b-1} =2$.  So $b-1 =0$ and $b=1$ and $n = 3^1=3$.

If $n = 2^a3^b$ then $\phi(n) = 2^{a-1}3^{b-1}(2-1)(3-1) = 2\cdot 2^{a-1}3^{b-1} = 2^a3^{b-1} =2$.  So $a =1$ and $b-1 =0$ and $b=1$ and $n = 2^1\cdot 3^1 = 6$.

And of course if $n= 1$ then $\phi(n)=\phi(1) =1\ne 2$

So $4,3,6$ are the only three options for $\phi(n) =2$.